# Кастомизировать MenuItem WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

При ховере на `MenuItem` он приобретает не совсем привлекательный вид. Как менять тот же `Background` при ховере что бы он не был таким?
Вот как он выглядит сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка:

```
<Menu x:Name="NavigationMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="419" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Background="#FFFF8080">
        <MenuItem Header="Settings" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="24" Height="40" Width="98" Margin="0,250,0,0" MouseEnter="MenuItem_MouseEnter"/>
</Menu>
```

Вот код которым пытался менять:

```
private void MenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   ( (MenuItem)sender ).Background = NavigationMenu.Background;
}
```

Comment: На меню есть дефолтние триггеры попробуйте их переопределить при помощи стилей

Comment: Можете показать как, не приходилось ещё менять дефолтные стили элементов.

Comment: Каким образом я могу вам его показать?

Comment: Ну на примере, я не знаю. У меня не получается убрать синий фон который появляется при ховере. Как его можно было бы убрать

Comment: Как его убрать - переопределить стиль. Забудьте вы про работу с контролами (а темнолицее с их стилями) через код, в WPF это не очень хорошо. Для стилей есть XAML, так что мешает там написать необходимый вид итема?

Comment: @SeeSharp Вот https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pZ0DiqxzU36jJKb1mNtiip0yh55mcLdD ищите стили Предназначенные для вашего елемента и подключайте как статические ресурсы. Методом научного тыка (мой любимый метод) разберетесь